# Centos 7 unable to connect to smtps server "No route to host"

Tags: centos, firewall, smtps

I have 2 PC (the second is a clone of first) running centos 7.
From one is not possible to send mail.
I did some tests and the result is this:

```
[root@PC2]# telnet smtps.aruba.it 465
Trying 62.149.156.218...
Connected to smtps.aruba.it.
Escape character is '^]'.

[root@PC1]# telnet smtps.aruba.it 465
Trying 62.149.128.218...
telnet: connect to address 62.149.128.218: No route to host
Trying 62.149.156.218...
telnet: connect to address 62.149.156.218: No route to host
```

PC1 returns "no route to host" but on the (global network) firewall I log packets that exit from PC1 to host.
All network configurations are the same in the subnet. What else can be the problem?

[image]

And more, if I try to connect to port 25 (that i know is NOT allowed) I receive allways double message:

```
[root@PC1]# telnet smtps.aruba.it 25
Trying 62.149.156.218...
telnet: connect to address 62.149.156.218: Connection refused
Trying 62.149.128.218...
telnet: connect to address 62.149.128.218: No route to host
```

while on other pc I have the right behavior

```
[root@PC2]# telnet smtps.aruba.it 25
Trying 62.149.156.218...
telnet: connect to address 62.149.156.218: Connection refused
Trying 62.149.128.218...
telnet: connect to address 62.149.128.218: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to firewall settings.
You can configure it or completely disable (Please, don't do that)

[Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-using-firewalld-on-centos-7) you can find the setup manual

Comment: Hi, 2 pc have teh same firewall rule. 
I also tried to disable firewall just for be sure that is not pc firewall the problem.